How to sign PDFs using "GOST-3411-2015-512" and "ECGOST3411-2015-512"?
I using old iText 2.1.7 in a legacy project. I'm working with KalkanProvider and BouncyCastle for cryptographic operations. I need to signing PDFs using the "GOST-3411-2015-512" and "ECGOST3411-2015-512" algorithms, but signature is invalid: Signature is invalid.
Here is my code:
def postProcessPdf(pdf: Array[Byte], os: OutputStream): Unit = {
    val reader = new PdfReader(pdf)
    val stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\u0000')          
    val appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance
    val signDate = Calendar.getInstance
    val pdfSignature = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED)
    pdfSignature.setDate(new PdfDate(signDate))
    pdfSignature.setCert(CryptUtils.cert.getEncoded)
    appearance.setCryptoDictionary(pdfSignature)
    appearance.setCrypto(null, CryptUtils.chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED)
    appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED)
    val estimatedSize = 8192
    val exc = new HashMap[PdfName, Int]()
    exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, estimatedSize * 2 + 2)
    appearance.preClose(exc)
    val data = appearance.getRangeStream()
    val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("GOST-3411-2015-512","KALKAN")
    val dataBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(data)
    digest.update(dataBytes)
    val appeareanceHash = digest.digest()
    val signature = Signature.getInstance("GOST3411-2015withECGOST3410-2015-512","KALKAN")
    signature.initSign(CryptUtils.privateKey)
    signature.update(appeareanceHash)
    val signedHash = signature.sign()
    val encodedPKCS7 = createCMS(signedHash, CryptUtils.cert,CryptUtils.privateKey)
    val paddedSig = new Array[Byte](estimatedSize)
    System.arraycopy(encodedPKCS7, 0, paddedSig, 0, encodedPKCS7.length)
    val dic = new PdfDictionary()
    dic.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true))
    appearance.close(dic)
}

I know this old library doesn't support these algorithms, so I tried to change the class PdfPKCS7.class, but it still couldn't work, maybe i made a mistake somewhere: PdfPKCS7.java
Next step i tried to use Kalkan classes for method createCMS:
def createCMS(data: Array[Byte], cert: X509Certificate, key: PrivateKey): Array[Byte] = {
    val generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator
    generator.addSigner(key, cert,"1.2.398.3.10.1.3.3")
    val chainStore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
    new CollectionCertStoreParameters(CryptUtils.chain.toSeq.asJava),
    KalkanProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
    generator.addCertificatesAndCRLs(chainStore)
    val content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data)
    val signedData = generator.generate(content, false, KalkanProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
    signedData.getEncoded
}

Signature still is invalid: PDF-file.
What i supposed to do? Thank you in advance for your help.

Have a look at the PDF specification 12.8.3.1 "Signature interoperability - General" where you will find the allowed digest algorithms. The ones you mention are not on the list. The PDF extensions TS-32001 and TS-32002 don't mention them either.

If I recall correctly, there is an Acrobat plug-in that adds support for certain GOST algorithms. Are you using such a plug-in?

@mkl no, i didn't know about this plugin. maybe this plugin is only for russian gost algorithm, i'm not sure if it is compatible with kazakhstani gost.

If there are differences between those GOST algorithms, it may be incompatible. But in that case your only hope would be to find a similar plugin for the kazakhstani algorithms.
